# subscribe to IE process

Tags: c#

Is it possible to subscribe to IE process. Anytime an Internet Explorer window is opened i would like to get an event triggered in windows form/console app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you could use a windows hook to do something like this but the only hooks supported in the .net framework are mouse and keyboard events. Refer to this article for what I mean:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804

So what you could do is just periodically poll the running processes on the machine by using this call:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
```

That should get you started.